# NodeJS ES6: Unexpecter character '#' for private class field declaration

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs, private

I have defined a class with a private class field as below

```
class BaseModel {
    #database = null
}
export default BaseModel
```

But when I try to compile it with babel using the command npm start, it gives the error saying

> SyntaxError: src/helpers/BaseModel.js: Unexpected character '#' (5:1)

If I try to run it with the Node command

> Node app.js

It works. My node version is v18.17.1.
How do I get the babel to compile this?

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npx nodemon src/app.js",
    "build": "npm run clean && npm run build-babel",
    "start": "npm run build && node ./build/app.js",
    "clean": "rm -rf build && mkdir build",
    "build-babel": "babel -d ./build ./src -s",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm install && npm run build"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.23.2",
    "@babel/register": "^7.22.15",
    "axios": "^1.5.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "firebase-admin": "^11.10.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "mysql2": "^3.6.1",
    "winston": "^3.10.0",
    "winston-daily-rotate-file": "^4.7.1"
  }
}
```

Also, here is my .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["env"]
}
```

Comment: Side note: you need to use `import "dotenv/config"` instead of `import "dotenv"; dotenv.config()`, otherwise other modules you import from this file will _not_ see the config, even though you may have placed their `import` statements below this line! (See [here](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#how-do-i-use-dotenv-with-import) why that is.)

Comment: [The changelog for 7.1.0](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/6f59f9227920765c5ef75a2f2d78d2aab9bcc179/.github/CHANGELOG-v7.0.0-v7.14.9.md#v710-2018-09-17) seems to indicate that it was added then, so 6.26.0 might not support private class fields. I haven't done a deep dive, so I might be mistaken on this.

Comment: @jabaa I get the error when I run transpile the code. Also, I have added the babel configuration file ".babelrc" it just contains {"presets": ["env"]}

Comment: @jabaa No matching version found for babel-register@^7.1.0

Comment: Try 7.23.2 or 7.22.15. You can find the current version on https://www.npmjs.com/package/@babel/core and https://www.npmjs.com/package/@babel/register

Comment: @jabaa Tried them both. Still same error. Updated my package.json. Can you please check it?

Comment: @RickN Have updated to 7.23.2. But it still gives the same error